# Left join by max and group by multiple values

Tags: sql

In the following query I want to join two tables so I have the latest timestamp and a status for table_b (not the latest timestamp for each status, which happens currently). Could you advice, how I can rewrite my query so instead of this (I omitted the unnecessary fields)

```
id           timestamp           status
7683295      1518621510130       "pending"
7683295      1518625048458       "unmatched"
```

it returns this

```
id           timestamp           status
7683295      1518625048458       "unmatched"
```

The query itself

```
SELECT
    table_a.id,
    COALESCE(table_b.status, 'new'),
    table_a.description,
    table_a.title,
    table_a.category,
    table_a.not_approved_timestamp,
    table_b.timestamp
FROM [table_a_location] AS table_a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, status, max(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM [table_b_location]
    GROUP BY id, status) as table_b
ON table_a.id == table_b.id
WHERE (table_a.approved_market_sku_id IS NULL AND table_b.status NOT IN ('pending'))
OR (table_a.not_approved_timestamp > table_a.approved_timestamp AND table_b.status NOT IN ('pending', 'unmatched'))

LIMIT 100
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `or table_b.status IS NULL` twice, to the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Veljko89, SQL Server and `LIMIT`?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.) Formatted text, not images.) Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before spending too much time.

Comment: @jarlh It seems to work. Could you, please, explain the mechanism? Sorry, I'm just quiet new to SQL.

Comment: @jarlh Limit wasn't there when I posted comment / or I didn't saw it

Comment: @Veljko89, still no good guess.

Comment: @Dronich, to include left side table rows without any right side table matches.

Comment: @jarlh Ah, no, it does not work. It still returns the following result

`id                 timestamp                status`

`7683295      1518621510130       "matched"`

`7683295      1518625048458       "canceled"`

I want only the latest status for each unique id

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `where` clause turns the outer join into an inner join, so it is misleading to use `left join`.

Your problem is that you are getting a separate row for each status.  I assume you want just the most recent one, so this `FROM` clause might fix your problem:

```
FROM [table_a_location] table_a JOIN
     (SELECT id, max(timestamp) AS timestamp
      FROM [table_b_location]
      GROUP BY id
     ) max_table_b
     ON table_a.id = max_table_b.id JOIN
     table_b_location table_b
     ON max_table_b.id = table_b.id AND max_table_b.timestamp = table_b.timestamp
```